# TabLayout click tab manually

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a ViewPagerAdapter like below.

```
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(), "THREE");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment4(), "FOUR");
```

I am attaching my viewpagesAdapter to a TabLayout

```
 tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

And then, I'm hiding the tab-4

```
 ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

My question is how I can trigger the click of tab-4 in the new button's click event. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want after clicking the tab 4? Do you want to make it visible again? And set the tab selected as well? You can implement the click listener easily like the way you have implemented the other. Please clarify.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Normally, if tab-4 is visible, when I click it, it opens the viewer of the fragment4. I want to do the same thing clicking any button when I hide the tab-4.

Comment: It looks like so simple from my view. I do not understand the complexity yet. You just have to make the fragment visible again and set the tab 4 selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click a tab programatically use:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
```

In your case `index = 3`;